# how to select datetime near 3 hours in mysql

Tags: mysql

I stored datatime of articule in my mysql table, when he will expired from shop , 
need me a query where to select articules where they will expired not more before 3 hours

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INTERVAL`

```
SELECT * FROM articles
  WHERE expires BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

the `BETWEEN` is used to check that expiration time is
(1) in the  future (filter out already expired)
and (2) within the next 3 hours

Comment: SELECT end_date_time 
FROM auctions_search 
WHERE end_date_time > NOW() 
 AND < NOW() + INTERVAL 3 HOUR

tryyed reciving error

Comment: @user2610360 reload the solution ;) i've been typing too fast. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT * from `table` where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `date_field`, NOW)<180;
```

Comment: Should be now()